# php form issue no data inserted if image input empty

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I use this form to insert data in my db:

```
<form action="demandes-de-tatouage.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="name"><label for="name">Nom:</label></div>
<div class="controls"><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="name" value="" /></div>
<div id="name"><label for="name">Email:</label></div>
<div class="controls"><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="email" value="" /></div>

<div id="description"><label for="description">Description:</label></div>
<div class="controls"><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="description" value="" /></div>
<div id="name"><label for="name">Partie du corps:</label></div>
<div class="controls"><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="partie" value="" /></div>

<div id="image"><label for="image">Envoyez vos images</label></div>
<div class="controls"><input id="image" name="image" type="file" value="" maxlength="100000" /> </div></br>
<div class="controls"><input id="image2" name="image2" type="file" value="" maxlength="100000" /> </div></br>

<input class="btn2" name="btn2" type="submit" value="Envoyer" /></form>
```

and this :

```
  <?php
 $host = "";
 $databasename = "";
 $user = "";
 $pass = "";
 /**********MYSQL Settings****************/

 $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

 if ($conn) {
     $db_selected = mysql_select_db($databasename, $conn);
     if (!$db_selected) {
         die('Can\'t use foo : '.mysql_error());
     }
 } else {
     die('Not connected : '.mysql_error());
 }

 $name = $_POST["name"];
 //email:
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 //description:
 $description = $_POST["description"];
 //partie:
 $partie = $_POST["partie"];

 function GetImageExtension($imagetype) {
     if (empty($imagetype)) {
         return false;
     }
     switch ($imagetype) {
         case 'image/bmp':
             return '.bmp';
         case 'image/gif':
             return '.gif';
         case 'image/jpeg':
             return '.jpg';
         case 'image/png':
             return '.png';
         default:
             return false;
     }
 }

 if (!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {

     $file_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
     $temp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
     $imgtype = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
     $ext = GetImageExtension($imgtype);
     $imagename = $file_name."-".date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
     $target_path = "images/assets/syltattoo/Emails/".$imagename;
     if (!empty($_FILES["image2"]["name"])) {

         $file_name2 = $_FILES["image2"]["name"];
         $temp_name2 = $_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"];
         $imgtype2 = $_FILES["image2"]["type"];
         $ext2 = GetImageExtension($imgtype2);
         $imagename2 = $file_name2."-".date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext2;
         $target_path2 = "images/assets/syltattoo/Emails/".$imagename2;

         if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path) && move_uploaded_file($temp_name2, $target_path2)) {
             $query_upload = "INSERT INTO `modx_demandes`(image, image2, name, email, description, partie) VALUES

('".$target_path."','".$target_path2."','$name', '$email', '$description', '$partie')";
             mysql_query(
             $query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());
         } else {

             exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
         }

     }
 }
```

My problem is that if user filled all fields except iamge & image2 nothing is inserted in data base. If every fields are filled everything is ok. So i have two questions:
1- How can i make it works with empty fields ? 
2- How to redirect aftr form success ?
Thank you

Comment: I would start here `if (!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {`

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the only time you insert into the database is within the:

`if (!empty($_FILES["image2"]["name"])) { /* ... */ }` block.

So if the user has not used the `image2` field when using the form the program will not execute the block of code contained within.

to redirect in php use the following

`header('Location: someplace.php');`